# Calling a complicated method from another method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, methods, cgrect

I've seen many cases here where someone asks how to call one extremely simply-named method from another method, and gets a simple answer.

However, I have a CGRect method

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect { /* code that draws circles */}
```

which successfully draws *nmax* circles for me.
I also have a button method that successfully updates an "*nmax*" displayed on the screen.

```
- (IBAction)changeIntValue:(id)sender {nmax=nmax+100;}
```

Only problem is that I want it to redraw the screen for me as well. I cannot for the life of me figure out, even after Ring some FM's, the syntax to "re-call" this rect down again in my changeIntValue method.

Any help greatly appreciated.
While I'm typing, if anyone has a reference with exhaustive info on syntax, that would be helpful.  References at developer.apple.com and most tutorials veer off into giving specific examples likeThisExample.  I hand-wrote some notes off a youtube lecture which gave syntax, but lost the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cause an item to redraw using

```
[view setNeedsDisplay];
```

where `view` is obviously your view.
This causes the view to be redrawn in the UI thread, and your view drawing code should then call your drawRect methods as appropriate.